# Brother Trouble

Tags: mathematics, geometry

[image]

Three Brothers Decided to purchase circular land(marked in red)
if the price of entire Circular land(circle P) = $29670

How Much They have to pay for the land marked in RED ??

Useful information:
1) Circle Q = Circle R (Equal size)
2) Circle Q, R touching at center(C) of P
3) **Red** circle touching circle Q, R, S
4) Circle S touching Circle Q, R, P

Clue : 
Solution can be derived by using very specific method/theory of circle

Answer (score 4):

There's a cute formula relating the radii of four mutually tangent circles. If we write $c_i=1/r_i$ then we have $\sum c^2=\frac12\left(\sum c\right)^2$. If tangency is internal to one circle, the sign of the corresponding $c$ needs to be changed.

So, let's say the radius of circle P is 1.

> The radii of Q,R are 1/2. So writing $c$ for the reciprocal of the radius of S, we have $((-1)^2+2^2+2^2+c^2)=\frac12(-1+2+2+c)^2$ which simplifies to $(c-3)^2=0$. (The squaring corresponds to the fact that there are two places we can put circle P, with the same radius in either case.)

Now look at circles Q,R,S and the red one, which I'll call T. This time write $c$ for the reciprocal of the radius of circle T. We have

> $2^2+2^2+3^2+c^2=\frac12(2+2+3+c)^2$ which simplifies to $(c+1)(c-15)=0$. The solution $c=-1$ of course corresponds to getting the original circle P back again; the one we want is $c=15$.

So

> the radius of the red circle is 1/15 that of the outer circle, and (making the obvious albeit not very plausible assumptions about land prices) they will have to pay $\$\frac{1978}{15}$ or approximately $\$131.87$.

Comment: My calculation agrees with yours.

Comment: I was expecting to see the word Apollonian somewhere.

Comment: OK, here's the word Apollonian: If you repeat this construction, so that every gap between 3 circles eventually gets a new tangent circle placed in it, the result is a fractal called an Apollonian gasket. Happy now? :-)